# fish abbreviation for range expansion

Tags: fish

I want a fish shell abbreviation which will convert `{218..220}` to `(seq 218 220)`.

I have written the abbreviation till:

```
function range_expansion
    # $argv
    # echo (seq 218 220) 
end

abbr --add range_expansion --position anywhere --regex "{\d+\.\.\d+}" --function range_expansion
```

I have a hunch that the regex is not working. Not understanding how to proceed from here.

Comment: Braces are special regex characters: you need to escape them too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do what you want:

```bash
function range_expansion
    # Replace all non-digits with spaces, then split on whitespace.
    set -l values (echo $argv | tr -cs '[:digit:]' ' ' | string split ' ' --no-empty)
    echo "(seq $values[1] $values[2])"
end

abbr --add range_expand_abbr --position anywhere --regex "\{\d+\.\.\d+\}" --function range_expansion
```

As Glenn Jackman observes, almost everything you want to match is a regex special character, so needs escaping. There are hardly any escapes in fish quoted strings, so these backslashes are passed to the regex engine.

There's multiple ways to extract the numbers from a string like `{123..456}`; here I've used `tr` and `string split` but there are certainly others.

Comment: fantastic & beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

The following address the edge case of word before sequence.

```
function range_expansion
    set -l value $argv

    set -l word_before_value (echo $value | cut -d\{ -f1)
    set -l from_value (echo $value | grep -oP "{\K.*?(?=\.)")
    set -l to_value (echo $value | grep -oP "\.\.\K.*(?=})")

    echo "$word_before_value(seq $from_value $to_value)"
end

abbr --add range_expand_abbr --position anywhere --regex "\w*\{\d+\.\.\d+\}" --function range_expansion
```

now you can run `mkdir tmux{1..5}` in addition to `mkdir {1..5}`.

**Update 1:**

If you do not want to use external tools in `range_expansion` function, then you can use the following function.

```
function range_expansion
    set -l value (string match --all --regex "\w*" $argv | string split ' ' --no-empty)
    set -l word_before_value
    set -l from_value
    set -l to_value

    math $value[1] &>/dev/null
    if test $status -ne 0
        # if first value is string
        set word_before_value $value[1]
        set from_value $value[2]
        set to_value $value[3]
    else
        # if first value is integer
        set from_value $value[1]
        set to_value $value[2]
    end

    echo "$word_before_value(seq $from_value $to_value)"
end
```